# Как запустить виртуальную среду venv через консоль PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

ДЕнь добрый!
Изучаю django и Python для вэб.

Python поставил версию 3.7 для работы с Pandas бесплатно )

При перезапуске Windows запуская Pycharm вижу `PS D:\django-sites\...`, но не `(venv) D:\django-sites...\`

[image: Скриншот]

Какая комманда запускает вертуальную среду?

Где найти комманду для консоли Pycharm?

PS - условное значение локального диска?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании нового проекта в PyCharm, виртуальная среда автоматически запускается. Если вы скачали код с github, то виртуальную среду можно включить следующими командами:

```py
PS D:\django-sites\testsite\> python -m venv venv
PS D:\django-sites\testsite\> venv\Scripts\activate
```

Возможно виртуальная среда у вас уже установлена. Зайдите в PyCharm:
`File > Settings > Tools > Terminal`. Внутри Terminal:  `Application Settings > Shell path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe.` Сохраните изменения и перейдите в терминал. Теперь у вас должно отображаться без знака PS:

```
(venv) D:\django-sites\testsite\>
```

Если у вас нет надписи (venv), то проделайте команды выше!
После этого у вас установлена виртуальная среда!

PS - это означает, что у вас командная строка PowerShell

Comment: Большое спасибо. Кажется ))) помогло. Стоял "PowerShell.exe" вместо "cmd.exe" 
Сейчас запускается [Скриншот](https://prnt.sc/HRlPHgYB5hi0) `(testsite) D:\django-sites\testsite\venv>`